# What does the Emergency Avionics switch do?

Tags: general-aviation, avionics

In almost every light aircraft I've ever flown, I recall their being a rocker switch marked "Emergency Avionics". Here's an example:

[image]

It's never really occurred to me to ask an instructor/owner what it does nor when to use it. Can somebody here explain what it does exactly?

Also, it appears to always be an aftermarket addition (the switch never quite matches the rest of the panel), could there perhaps be a reason why this second avionics master was added?

Comment: My light aircraft doesn't have a switch like that...

Comment: I have no such switch in my plane.  I do however have 2 Avionics Master switches wired in parallel, either will power up the Avionics power buss.  They were installed in place of an Avionics Master relay (which was removed) that could potentially fail closed and let high, spikey voltage from the alternator onto the buss during startup (or engine shutdown) and damage the avionics. I turn one of them on after the engine is started, and back off before the engine is shut down.

Comment: In what type of aircraft was this picture taken? Between aircraft with avionics from steam to Garmin, Avidyne, and Dynon, this is the first time I’ve seen an “Emergency Avionics” switch.

Comment: @DeanF. This is a PA28, and I've certainly seen it in other PA28's. Don't recall seeing one in C150152/172's but haven't flown one in a number of years.

Comment: I Have flown various Archers, Cherokees, and Warriors. I wonder if this was specific to a certain run of model years. Any clue?

Comment: Doubt it. This one's a late 90's model, Ive flown various older ones and seen it thoughout. I'm almost certain this switch is aftermarket, as they never seem to match the rest of the switches. I wonder if it was a change that was rolled out across the entire range for some reason.

Comment: I just pulled up pictures of the panels of club Pipers I’ve rented. Just in case I overlooked or forgot about this switch. None of them have it. That makes me kind of curious what AD or SB prompted this. And, if I need to make the clubs aware.

Comment: Check the AFM for that aircraft.  It should be listed there.

Comment: Ok. So, I searched through the AFM for the PA28-(150, 160, & 180), revised May 10, 1977, and the POHs for the PA28-181, revised January 05, 2004, and revised May 07, 2018. None of the three had an Emergency Avionics switch on the panel nor in the electrical system diagrams. Poster Fiddlesticks posted a diagram for a PA28-236 Dakota that does have it. Besides the O-540 engine, does anyone know the differences that would warrant the additional switch?

Comment: Well, this may not be an answer. Rather, it’s a supposition or a theory. Since the Dakota POH says that the Master switch and the Alternator switch are mechanically interlocked, the Emergency Avionics switch may be the back-up if you have to disengage the alternator. Turning off the Alternator would also switch off the Master. My question is if it is a Off/On switch like it says? Or, is it an Off/Armed Switch like it is with more recently built Essentials Busses and stand-by/emergency batteries? The On/Off variety would require the pilot to actively select it in the case of electrical problems

Comment: I've flown a good handful of light airplane makes and models and none have a switch like you describe.

Comment: @quietflyer - Yes, I thought the same thing. I’ve flown quite a few G500 & G1000 aircraft with an Off/Armed switch for the standby battery/avionics systems. I had never seen an Off/On switch for Emergency Avionics in what appears to be a steam gauge panel. Yet, Fiddlesticks has found a legitimate reference showing it in the Dakota. I would love to know the official reasoning behind this switch. Especially since the referenced diagram does not have an additional power source represented. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

A quick google will turn up some answers. The consensus seems to be that it is just another switch in parallel with the Avionics Master Switch, such that, if the master switch fails, the "emergency" switch can be used to connect the juice instead! The point being that the master switch is a single  point of failure for the entire avionics suite (radios, transponder and nav) - if that switch fails in flight, you lose everything!

EDIT:

From the [Piper Dakota (PA-28-236) Maintenance Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/866705/Piper-Dakota.html?page=175#manual):

> Electrical power for various avionics components is controlled by an avionics master switch located near
>   the top of the instrument panel between radio stacks. It controls power to all radios through the aircraft master
>   switch.
>
> An emergency bus switch is provided to supply auxiliary power to avionics bus in event of a radio master
>   switch circuit failure. The emergency bus switch is located behind lower right shin guard, to left of the circuit
>   breaker panel.

[image]

Comment: This is largely unfounded and likely incorrect (insofar as this serves as the backup for the master avionics switch as a component).

Comment: The Dakota POH you referenced says that the Master and Alternator switches are mechanically interlocked. Could the Emergency Avionics switch be in case you have to disengage the alternator due to excessive amps or voltage? In which case, you would still be able to manually select battery power to the avionics when the Alternator/Master combo switch were turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered this personally myself, but a Google search indicates that the emergency avionics switch is usually used in setup where a relay is used to control the power to the avionics bus.  If the relay were to fail the emergency avionics switch would bypass it.  Relays allow the reduction of high current wiring having to run to the panel with a high current switch.  Instead the switch is a low power switch which drives a relay which would be located closer to the actual avionics bus so not as much wiring would be needed.  More high current wiring increases the risk of hazardous electrical shorts and electrical fires, however mechanical relays do fail eventually.  So the emergency avionics power switch will bypass the mechanical relay in case it fails.

Comment: That seems to be self-defeating. You have to run the high-current wire to the emergency switch *anyway*, so all that does is add one low-current wire.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield:  I agree which I think is why most planes don't have this configuration.  There are places where a relay would make sense, like the starter circuit, but I don't think a relay on the avionics bus makes much sense.